# What tools in Python are available for doing great circle distance + line creation?

Tags: python, distance, polyline-creation, great-circle

I need to use Python to create a great circle distance -- both a number, and preferably some kind of 'curve' that I can use to draw in a client-side map. I don't care about the format of the curve -- be it WKT, or a set of pairs of coordinates -- but just want to get the data out.

What tools are there out there? What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some links that might help:

http://www.koders.com/python/fid0A930D7924AE856342437CA1F5A9A3EC0CAEACE2.aspx
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/393241-calculating-the-distance-between-zip-codes/

Comment: note that the koders.com link is dead, redirecting to ohloh.

Answer (score 15):

[pyproj](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/) has the [Geod.npts](https://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/pyproj.Geod-class.html#npts) function that will return an array of points along the path. Note that it doesn't include the terminal points in the array, so you need to take them into account:

```
import pyproj
# calculate distance between points
g = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')
(az12, az21, dist) = g.inv(startlong, startlat, endlong, endlat)

# calculate line string along path with segments <= 1 km
lonlats = g.npts(startlong, startlat, endlong, endlat,
                 1 + int(dist / 1000))

# npts doesn't include start/end points, so prepend/append them
lonlats.insert(0, (startlong, startlat))
lonlats.append((endlong, endlat))
```

Comment: Thanks! Solution provided by well-known & massively used library here :)

Comment: Great answer. I would just add that by setting the initial_idx and terminus_idx arguments within g.npts to 0, the output list will also include the initial and terminal points, which eliminates the need to manually insert them into your list.

Comment: @KBurchfiel - my answer is very old. Pyproj may not have had that capability when I wrote this. But thanks for the update!

Answer (score 11):

GeographicLib has a [python interface](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/):

This can computer geodesics on an ellipsoid (set flattening to zero to get great circles) and can generate intermediate points on a geodesic (see the "Line" commands in the sample).

Here's how to print out points on the geodesic line from
JFK to Changi Airport (Singapore):

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
geod = Geodesic.WGS84

g = geod.Inverse(40.6, -73.8, 1.4, 104)
l = geod.Line(g['lat1'], g['lon1'], g['azi1'])
num = 15  # 15 intermediate steps

for i in range(num+1):
    pos = l.Position(i * g['s12'] / num)
    print(pos['lat2'], pos['lon2'])

->
(40.60, -73.8)
(49.78, -72.99)
(58.95, -71.81)
(68.09, -69.76)
(77.15, -65.01)
(85.76, -40.31)
(83.77, 80.76)
(74.92, 94.85)
...
```

Comment: The python port of GeographicLib is now available at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib

Comment: See also this paper: C. F. F. Karney, Algorithms for Geodesics, J. Geod, DOI: dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z

Answer (score 8):

The answers provided by others are a little more elegant, but here's an ultrasimple, somewhat unpythonic, bit of Python that provides the basics. The function takes two coordinate pairs and a user-specified number of segments. It yields a set of intermediate points along a great circle path. Output: text ready to write as KML. Caveats: The code does not consider antipodes, and assumes a spherical earth.

Code by Alan Glennon http://enj.com July 2010 (author places this code in the public domain. Use at your own risk).

--

def tweensegs(longitude1,latitude1,longitude2,latitude2,num_of_segments):

```
import math

ptlon1 = longitude1
ptlat1 = latitude1
ptlon2 = longitude2
ptlat2 = latitude2

numberofsegments = num_of_segments
onelessthansegments = numberofsegments - 1
fractionalincrement = (1.0/onelessthansegments)

ptlon1_radians = math.radians(ptlon1)
ptlat1_radians = math.radians(ptlat1)
ptlon2_radians = math.radians(ptlon2)
ptlat2_radians = math.radians(ptlat2)

distance_radians=2*math.asin(math.sqrt(math.pow((math.sin((ptlat1_radians-ptlat2_radians)/2)),2) + math.cos(ptlat1_radians)*math.cos(ptlat2_radians)*math.pow((math.sin((ptlon1_radians-ptlon2_radians)/2)),2)))
# 6371.009 represents the mean radius of the earth
# shortest path distance
distance_km = 6371.009 * distance_radians

mylats = []
mylons = []

# write the starting coordinates
mylats.append([])
mylons.append([])
mylats[0] = ptlat1
mylons[0] = ptlon1 

f = fractionalincrement
icounter = 1
while (icounter <  onelessthansegments):
        icountmin1 = icounter - 1
        mylats.append([])
        mylons.append([])
        # f is expressed as a fraction along the route from point 1 to point 2
        A=math.sin((1-f)*distance_radians)/math.sin(distance_radians)
        B=math.sin(f*distance_radians)/math.sin(distance_radians)
        x = A*math.cos(ptlat1_radians)*math.cos(ptlon1_radians) + B*math.cos(ptlat2_radians)*math.cos(ptlon2_radians)
        y = A*math.cos(ptlat1_radians)*math.sin(ptlon1_radians) +  B*math.cos(ptlat2_radians)*math.sin(ptlon2_radians)
        z = A*math.sin(ptlat1_radians) + B*math.sin(ptlat2_radians)
        newlat=math.atan2(z,math.sqrt(math.pow(x,2)+math.pow(y,2)))
        newlon=math.atan2(y,x)
        newlat_degrees = math.degrees(newlat)
        newlon_degrees = math.degrees(newlon)
        mylats[icounter] = newlat_degrees
        mylons[icounter] = newlon_degrees
        icounter += 1
        f = f + fractionalincrement

# write the ending coordinates
mylats.append([])
mylons.append([])
mylats[onelessthansegments] = ptlat2
mylons[onelessthansegments] = ptlon2

# Now, the array mylats[] and mylons[] have the coordinate pairs for intermediate points along the geodesic
# My mylat[0],mylat[0] and mylat[num_of_segments-1],mylat[num_of_segments-1] are the geodesic end points

# write a kml of the results
zipcounter = 0
kmlheader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\"><Document><name>LineString.kml</name><open>1</open><Placemark><name>unextruded</name><LineString><extrude>1</extrude><tessellate>1</tessellate><coordinates>"
print kmlheader
while (zipcounter < numberofsegments):
        outputstuff = repr(mylons[zipcounter]) + "," + repr(mylats[zipcounter]) + ",0 "
        print outputstuff
        zipcounter += 1
kmlfooter = "</coordinates></LineString></Placemark></Document></kml>"
print kmlfooter
```

Answer (score 3):

geopy
A Geocoding Toolbox for Python

http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted#Calculating_distances

Comment: +1 Didn't see functionality to do intermediate points along the geodesic, but very good toolset to know about (handles ellipsoid calcs). Thx.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't used this package, but it seems interesting, and a possible solution: http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/Shapely

Comment: AFAIK, shapely doesn't do spheroidal calculations: `Shapely is a Python package for set-theoretic analysis and manipulation of **planar** features`