# Getting a "square" of lat/lon for database query

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, utm

So I want to get the square formed by a single point of lat/lons, my plan was to take that point's latitude, divide by 360, and multiply by the circumference of earth. Giving us the distance from the equator.

Now I will take 1/4 the circumference of earth, and subtract by the distance from the equator, giving us the height of triangle T. I can the find the base because I know the initial height, truncated height, and the original base.

Now using the base and height I can use trig to find the minimum and maximum longitude, and the latitude is easy because lets are evenly spaced. Does this sound right?

EDIT:

Let me simplify this question.

How can I find the distance between two points of longitude, at a single point of latitude?

Comment: The range of latitude values is not from 0->360.

Comment: I think you need to work with Projected coordinate system and not geographic lat/lng since you cannot perfrom measurements with lat/lng.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for exactly but maybe a look at [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), and [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) will get you closer.

Comment: Can you turn this into a comprehensive answer to the original question, paste it in below ("Your Answer") and click the tick (check) icon to make it "the answer"? Thanks

Comment: ya I can do that

Comment: Correct formulas appear in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

So for me the answer was, because I dont need that much accuracy, to use the Great-circle distance formula.

distance of one degree of longitude = Cos( longitude ) * radius * ( π / 180 ).

Distance of latitude = about 69 miles / degree

Comment: This formula is correct for *distance along a circle* (it appears in many places on this site) but **it is not the great-circle formula**: a circle of latitude is a great circle only at the Equator.  To see how incorrect it can be, consider the distance from, say, Mexico City (19.25, -99) and Bombay (19.25, +73) (which aren't too far from the Equator as it is). Your formula gives Cos(19.25)*(73+99)*69 = 11,200 miles, whereas the correct distance is 9730 miles. That 13% error is large.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with python? If you are there's another post which covers your Question!

[What tools in Python are available for doing great circle distance + line creation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-tools-in-python-are-available-for-doing-great-circle-distance-line-creati)