# How to determine vector between two lat/lon points

Tags: mathematics, latitude-longitude, great-circle, azimuth

For all the math geniuses out there...given two lat/lon points (point A and point B), what is the simplest way to find the vector needed to reach point B from point A. For example, the vector needed to reach 36, -85 from 36, -82 would be 270°. I am not entirely sure if "vector" is the technically correct term so if there is a more accurate term, comment and let me know. The fact that the earth is a sphere is throwing me off...I feel as if I could tackle this problem if given a plane but the sphere complicates it too much for me. A chunk of code would be ideal but a simple algorithm that I can translate into code myself is perfectly fine also.

Comment: You're looking for a [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) calculation. Take a look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/47/150) or [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2/150).

Comment: The Earth *isn't* a sphere -- it's a spheroid, which will mess up the accuracy of spherical trig.  The real solution is a partial differential equation, only solvable through iterative means.

Comment: The direction (or "bearing") from (36,-85) to (36,-82) is *not* 270 degrees! It is actually a bit greater than that.

Comment: If they're lat-lon coords, the bearing is just under 90°. If they're lon-lat coords, it is exactly 0°.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the **[initial bearing (or forward azimuth)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_%28navigation%29)**, which if followed in a straight line along a [**great-circle arc**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) will take you from the start point to the end point.

Here is some simple [JavaScript from this link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
        Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

The above link has a wealth of useful information beyond this for related calculations.

As your question states, this is the simplest method - since the Earth is not a true sphere this calculation will not be 100% accurate, but it is a close approximation.

Comment: If this is accurate within a few degrees that is fine. In the final product, this will be indiscernible due to the affects of pixel rounding. I'll try this out...looks promising!

Comment: If your tolerance is really "a few degrees" (though i suspect it's a bit tighter) then the spherical earth assumption will be plenty good enough for you.